# Unexpected white pixels when using terrain painting brush

Tags: unity, rendering, terrain

I have two texture layers in my terrain. When I paint the second layer on the base layer the results around some of the the joining areas will be like:
[image]

I can remove it by carefully painting over it but in some cases it just grows further and consumes a lot of time and energy. I'm using `Unity 2018.4.0f1` and have never seen such thing in older versions and 2019. However I have not used terrains very much. Tell me if you need any information in the comments.
I have tried the following approaches:

- Disabling Alpha Channel in texture import settings
- Testing both color spaces (Linear and Gamma)
- Using the same texture for both layers (The white line still exists)
- Using custom Diffuse Material

The problem seems to be the generated SplatAlpha texture:
[image]
As you can see four layers are generated: Red, Green and Black. But you can see the pixels I marked with blue and I don't know where are they coming from.
Why is that and how to solve it?

Comment: Do you see anything different if you first paint your terrain all-grass, then all-sand, then do your desired painting after "priming the canvas" this way?

Comment: @DMGregory No, the problem remains.

Comment: @DMGregory Any suggestion? I'm still stuck in it after two weeks.

Comment: If I had one, I'd have posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be the version `2018.4.0f1`. It's a bug in `SplatAlpha` generation. I've ported the project to `Unity 2020.2.7f1` and now it's working fine. It would have been better if there was a fix for 2018 because I really need to implement the game in that version.